# How can I enter 2 commands on Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

In the DOS command line, I used to be able to enter ¶ between commands to put multiple commands on one line.

For example, instead of typing

```
c:\> cls
c:\> cd
```

I could enter

```
c:\> cls¶cd
```

Has this functionality been removed or has this been replaced by something else?

How can I run multiple commands from one line?

Comment: `cls && cd` works in the WIN7 cmd.exe, but I'm not sure if it works in a dos shell

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `&`.

From the [documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true):

> `command1 & command2` : Use to separate multiple commands on one command
>   line. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then the second command.
>
> `command1 && command2` : Use to run the command following && only if the
>   command preceding the symbol is successful. Cmd.exe runs the first
>   command, and then runs the second command only if the first command
>   completed successfully.
>
> `command1 || command2` : Use to run the command following || only if the
>   command preceding || fails. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then
>   runs the second command only if the first command did not complete
>   successfully (receives an error code greater than zero).
>
> `(command1 & command2)` : Use to group or nest multiple commands.
>
> `command1 parameter1;parameter2`: Use to separate command parameters.

Comment: Does not work if first command is `cd`- got error:`Invalid arguments. Type cd <folder> to change the current working directory.`. What to do in this case?

Answer (score 5):

`&&`.  The double ampersand actually performs error checking.  If the commands to the left of the `&&` don't return with the expected result, the commands on the right aren't executed.

`cls && cd`

If you want to run the commands on both sides of the `&&`, use a single ampersand.

`cls & cd`

Comment: -1 && will run the second command only if the first is successful.

Comment: @dogbane: Please see my answer

Answer (score 4):

`cls & cd`

All you need is `&`

As others have stated, `&&` will only execute the second command if the first was successful.

`||` will execute the second command if the first failed.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks.  I like that command separator a hell of a lot better as well.

Comment: That doesnt display the `cd` command, plus when I tried it I couldn't move to another directory.

Comment: Wait ... cd is never run.

Comment: Whoa, I was in linux for a second. My fault, fixed.