# What is causing this error in command prompt

Tags: command-line

In trying to move to a folder called "Creating Project & External Execution"... with this command...

```
cd Creating Project & External Execution
```

This error occurs...

> The system cannot find the path specified.
>   'External' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Why does External in the folder name cause this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Can you post a screenshot of the typed command  before you press return?

Comment: It's not the 'External' that's causing the problem, it's the `&`, which has a special meaning to CMD. You may find [this SS64 reference page](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) useful.

Comment: The folder name has to be inside double quotes " " to be reading spaces. For example cd "Program Files"

Comment: @me_alok `cd Program Files` work as well. `cd` doesn't need quotes for file name with spaces. `cd /?` gives this `CHDIR command does not treat spaces as delimiters, so it is possible to
CD into a subdirectory name that contains a space without surrounding
the name with quotes` The only problem here is the `&`.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Thank you, i guess i usually followed what tab key said. The tab audo-completion adds quotes which made me think it does require quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it does. The command you must issue is:

```
cd "Creating Project & External Execution"
```

In this screenshot, you see that I have first issued your command, and then the one I recommended above, as well the results of each.

[image: Your command vs. my command]

The command that you are issuing is equal to the following two commands:

```
cd Creating Project
External Execution
```

The first results in this error:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

And the second results in this error:

> 'External' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows cmd `&` is a special character used for separating multiple commands on a single line

> ```
> & [...]     command1 & command2
> ```
>
> Use to separate multiple commands on one command line. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then the second command.
>
> [Command shell overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490954(v=technet.10))

As a result `cd Creating Project & External Execution` will be executed as

```
cd Creating Project
External Execution
```

as Fleet Command said. Since there's no folder called "Creating Project" and no command named `External`, you got the above errors.

---

To solve this you have to escape the `&` somehow. There are 2 ways:

- Put quotes around the name because inside quotes `&` loses its special meaning

  > If it is a quote (`"`) toggle the quote flag, if the quote flag is active, the following special characters are no longer special: `^ & | < > ( )`.
  >
  > [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/995714)

  ```
  cd "Creating Project & External Execution"
  ```
- Escape with `^`

  ```
  cd Creating Project ^& External Execution
  ```

No need to escape the spaces because `cd` works fine with spaces in filename<sup>1</sup>. But if you want you can still escape the spaces like this `cd Creating^ Project^ ^&^ External^ Execution` without problem

[image: cmd]

- [How can I enter 2 commands on Windows command line?](https://superuser.com/q/368793/241386)
- [How do I run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8055371/995714)

---

<sup>1</sup>Space is not a delimiter in `cd`

```
C:\>cd /?
Displays the name of or changes the current directory.

CHDIR [/D] [drive:][path]
CHDIR [..]
CD [/D] [drive:][path]
CD [..]

  ..   Specifies that you want to change to the parent directory.

...

CHDIR command does not treat spaces as delimiters, so it is possible to
CD into a subdirectory name that contains a space without surrounding
the name with quotes.  For example:

    cd \winnt\profiles\username\programs\start menu

is the same as:

    cd "\winnt\profiles\username\programs\start menu"

which is what you would have to type if extensions were disabled.
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to put the folder name between quotation mark " and ", that will be like that :

```
cd "your folder name"
```

Comment: you don't need to put folder name in quotes. `cd some folder` absolutely works without problem. The problem here is the `&` character